# Google Developer Account Terminated. Can I open another with the same name?

Tags: android

Despite my best efforts, one of my apps was taken down, I expect, for IP infringement, and resulted in my account being terminated. However, the account was getting kind of messy, and it's current income was only really going to decline. What I would like to know is whether it would be possible to open another account under the same name? I'm rather fond of my old alias, and would prefer to keep it in my future endeavors, if at all possible :)

All help appreciated!

EDIT: I understand this isn't a coding question, but I don't really know where else to turn.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google policies and not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Google's policies, not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming as defined in the help center.

Comment: "...I don't really know where else to turn." What about asking Google? They should know.